# Why won't pipe operator let me combine successive mutations?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, dplyr

I want to mutate columns from this...

[image]

...into...

[image]

When I did the following...

```
villastats<-villastats%>% 
  mutate(HG = ifelse(HomeTeam == "Aston Villa", villastats$FTHG, ifelse(HomeTeam != "Aston Villa", 0, 0)))
villastats<-villastats%>% 
  mutate(AG = ifelse(AwayTeam == "Aston Villa", villastats$FTAG, ifelse(AwayTeam != "Aston Villa", 0, 0)))
villastats<-villastats%>%
  mutate(THG=cumsum(villastats$HG))
villastats<-villastats%>%
  mutate(TAG=cumsum(villastats$AG))
villastats<-villastats%>%
  mutate(Tot=THG+TAG)
```

...it produced the result shown above that I wanted. I want to do all the mutations at once, so I tried

```
villastats<-villastats%>% 
  mutate(HG = ifelse(HomeTeam == "Aston Villa", villastats$FTHG, ifelse(HomeTeam != "Aston Villa", 0, 0)))%>%
  mutate(AG = ifelse(AwayTeam == "Aston Villa", villastats$FTAG, ifelse(AwayTeam != "Aston Villa", 0, 0)))%>%
  mutate(THG=cumsum(villastats$HG))
  mutate(TAG=cumsum(villastats$AG))%>%
  mutate(Tot=THG+TAG)
```

This didn't work. The first two lines work fine but when I add the third line it tells me

> Error: Column `THG` must be length 38 (the number of rows) or one, not 0 <

Where am I going wrong? Why is it doing this?

Comment: `villstats %>% mutate(HG = ifelse(...), AG = ifelse(...), THG = cumsum(...), TAG = cumsum(...), Tot = THG+TAG)`.

Comment: And stop using `villastats$` inside the call to mutate.

Comment: The issue is that you have put `villastats$` before `HG` and `AG`. `villastats` gets only updated after the final step of the pipeline. In the middle of the  pipeline `villastats` simply refers to the original dataset from which you started. Put differently, in the middle of the pipeline there are no columns `HG` and `AG` in `villastats`. Hence you get an error.

Comment: Please can you use ``dput(head(data))`` and edit your question to include the output rather than posting a screenshot. People can't reproduce your error from a screenshot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use `villastats$` inside a pipe that is derived from the object `villastats$` (as you are doing), then `villastats$$FTHG` refers to the version of the variable before the first step in your pipeline. For instance,

   ```r
   someframe <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 11:13) # <---------------------------\
   someframe %>%                                                             |
     mutate(a = a + 1) %>% # <-------------------------------------\         |
     mutate(a = a + 2) %>%       # <--- this 'a' is referring to --/         |
     mutate(a = someframe$a + 3) # <--- this 'someframe$a' is referring to --/
   ```

   In some simpler magrittr pipes, this is "fine" in that the version of the variable at the beginning is no different than at the time of referencing it. However, if there are fewer rows (`dplyr::filter`), different values (`mutate(a = a+2)`) or just reordering (`arrange`), then `a` can be *very different* from `someframe$a`. In the best case, you get an error because the length of the vector you're referencing is incompatible with the operation you're doing. In the *worst* case, it gives you no warning or error but all of your calculations are silently wrong.
2. You can place all of your `mutate` operations in one call, as in

   ```r
   villastats %>% 
     mutate(
       HG = ifelse(HomeTeam == "Aston Villa", FTHG,
                   ifelse(HomeTeam != "Aston Villa", 0, 0)),
       AG = ifelse(AwayTeam == "Aston Villa", FTAG,
                   ifelse(AwayTeam != "Aston Villa", 0, 0)),
       THG = cumsum(HG),
       TAG = cumsum(AG),
       Tot = THG+TAG
     )
   ```

   While what you did is not wrong, it is slower and perhaps a little harder to read.
3. Your `ifelse`s are unnecessarily nested. The first comparison `HomeTeam=="AstonVilla"` and the second comparison `HomeTeam!="AstonVilla"` are perfectly complementary, you can reduce all of those to just

   ```r
   villastats %>% 
     mutate(
       HG = ifelse(HomeTeam == "Aston Villa", FTHG, 0),
       AG = ifelse(AwayTeam == "Aston Villa", FTAG, 0),
       THG = cumsum(HG),
       TAG = cumsum(AG),
       Tot = THG + TAG
     )
   ```
4. Not that you asked, but I urge `dplyr::if_else` in place of base `ifelse`. The latter drops some classes (try `ifelse(TRUE, Sys.time(), Sys.time())` for an example) and allows the programmer to be sloppy by including different class objects in the "yes" and "no" options. `if_else` won't let you do `if_else(TRUE, "1", -3.14)`, since they are different. (It'll even complain about `if_else(TRUE, 0, 0L)`. It's strict.) Use it and be declarative, meaning using `0L` instead of `0` if you expect that your normal operation will be an integer, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering but both answers above (2 & 3) result in >Error: Column `THG` must be length 38 (the number of rows) or one, not 0<

Comment: I had an old version of code, just fixed, please check that. If that doesn't fix it, then ... I don't know. I'm working on code without data, so I have no way of actually *testing* this with data. Perhaps I could help if you [edit] your question and paste the output from `dput(head(villastats,n))` where `n` is big enough to show just enough variability in your data, but not so big as to bloat the question too much.

Comment: Both solutions worked after the edit. Thanks very much.