# Trying to loop through a list to do repeated mutations

Tags: r, for-loop, multiple-columns, dplyr

Thanks for help I have already received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325649/why-wont-pipe-operator-let-me-combine-successive-mutations/64326327#64326327) in turning...
this:
[image]

into this:
[image]

What I have done with just one team, Aston Villa, I now want to try with all the teams in the dataset. The first 15 lines of the data set are as follows:
[image]

I want to loop through the data and create the additional columns for ALL the teams just like I did for Aston Villa above.
First I created a list of the 20 teams and called it 'teams'. Then I tried...

```
for(i in teams){
  mydata %>% 
    mutate(
      HG = ifelse(HomeTeam == i, FTHG,
                  ifelse(HomeTeam != i, 0, 0)),
      AG = ifelse(AwayTeam == i, FTAG,
                  ifelse(AwayTeam != i, 0, 0)),
      THG = cumsum(HG),
      TAG = cumsum(AG),
      Tot = THG+TAG
    )
  
}
```

But the output only shows it working for one team, West Ham, like it only looped through for West Ham and then stopped. Even so it is not correct..
[image]

It should be showing a running total of the home goals, away goals and total scores by each team in the THG, TAG and Tot columns respectively, but that is not happening at all. It worked well when I separated out one team, Aston Villa, as above.

Where am I going wrong?

How can I save the output?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I was not able to understand what exactly you are trying to do, but loop+mutate makes you mutate all lines inside the loop...  and you overwrite what you have done in the previous loop.. Is not "West Ham" the last item in your object (vector) "teams"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you go through the list is wrong.

```
for (i in 1:length(teams)) {
  teams[[i]] ...
  ...
  
}
```